# Dynamic column name change based on date [T-SQL]

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

> Is there a way to make this work? change static, "**13MonthsAgo**"
>   into **January**?

Original

```
> COUNT(CASE WHEN dateadd(MONTH, - 13, getdate()) >
> HireDate AND dateadd(MONTH, - 13, getdate()) <
> TerminationDate OR
>TerminationDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 13Monthsago
```

Preferred

```
> COUNT(CASE WHEN dateadd(MONTH, - 13, getdate()) >
> HireDate AND dateadd(MONTH, - 13, getdate()) <
> TerminationDate OR
>TerminationDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS
>DATENAME(month, dateadd(MONTH,-13,getdate()))
```

Comment: If you are asking whether you can generate column names on-the-fly then have a look at [dynamic SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Then see [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/). Then think about what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: Okay, so its not that simple... thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lengthy approach but will work..

```
declare @MonthName varchar(20)

select 1 num, 'January' name into #Months
union
select 2 num, 'February' name
union
select 3 num, 'March' name
union
select 4 num, 'April' name
union
select 5 num, 'May' name
union
select 6 num, 'June' name
union
select 7 num, 'July' name
union
select 8 num, 'August' name
union
select 9 num, 'September' name
union
select 10 num, 'October' name
union
select 11 num, 'November' name
union
select 12 num, 'December' name

select @MonthName = name from #Months where datepart(mm,getdate()) = num

--Add the other columns to the dataset here
--This is just an example
select HireDate, TerminationDate, 
 COUNT(CASE WHEN dateadd(MONTH, - 13, getdate()) >
 HireDate AND dateadd(MONTH, - 13, getdate()) <
 TerminationDate OR
TerminationDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 13Monthsago
into #Dataset
FROM SomeTable GROUP BY HireDate, TerminationDate

use tempdb

EXEC sp_RENAME '#Dataset.13Monthsago' , @MonthName, 'COLUMN'

SELECT * FROM #Dataset
```

Comment: This works perfectly, Thank you! But how do I add 12MonthsAgo, 11MonthsAgo etc into this query?

Comment: Then what you need to do is get rid of the column name `13MonthAgo` and have a generic name like `SomeTimeAgo` and then create `#Dataset13`(for 13 months), `#Dataset12`(for 12 months)..etc and have all of their `SomeTimeAgo` column renamed as per the above logic.

Answer (score 0):

This could be one way to go about it.

```
;with cte_Dates AS
(
SELECT CAST('20150101' as DATEtime) as DateStr UNION ALL
SELECT '20150201' UNION ALL
SELECT '20150202' UNION ALL
SELECT '20150203' UNION ALL
SELECT '20150204' UNION ALL
SELECT '20150301' UNION ALL
SELECT '20150401' UNION ALL
SELECT '20150501' UNION ALL
SELECT '20150601' UNION ALL
SELECT '20150701' UNION ALL
SELECT '20150801' UNION ALL
SELECT '20150901' UNION ALL
SELECT '20151001' UNION ALL
SELECT '20151101' UNION ALL
SELECT '20151201'
)


SELECT      *  
FROM
    (SELECT DateStr,DATENAME(MONTH,DateStr) As MONTHS 
     FROM
            cte_Dates
     )P
        PIVOT
        (  
        count(DateStr)
        FOR MONTHS IN ([January], [February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],[December])
        )AS PVT
```